# How to stop SoundCloud tracks posted to site from looping/repeating in IE Explorer?

Tags: soundcloud

Adding code: "loop=false&amp" stopped the track from repeating in Chrome browsers but not IE.  Please advise solution for the IE browser based visitors to our sites....

Thanks!

Comment: Could you elaborate...??

Comment: I have a soundcloud track embedded onto a page on our company website. the track continually repeats. I added loop=false&amp to the embed code and that stopped the track from repeating, but only when the site/track is viewed from Chrome browsers. When the page is viewed and the track is accessed via IE browser, the track loops/repeats itself over and over again. Is there another piece of code I can add or something I can do to prevent this audio track from looping for site visitors who use Interet Explorer?

Comment: could you give us a link to the page? or maybe the code for the embed? thanks!